# Knapsack Representation

Tags: javascript

> Use reduce to compute the area of the largest rectangle in an array of
>   rectangles. Each rectangle has width and height properties, and if r
>   is a rectangle, the area is `r.width * r.height`
>
> If there are no rectangles, return 0, so the base case is 0. In the
>   online instruction examples, reduce() was used to form the sum over a
>   set of items. In this case you will want to take the maximum over a
>   set of items (using JavaScript’s Math.max(a, b) function.)
>
> You must use a function named area to compute and return the area of a
>   rectangle. It takes one parameter which is a rectangle object.
>
> You must also define a function to pass into reduce, analogous to the
>   sum_value function in “The Real Reduce” sub-lessons within the
>   “Knapsack: Representation” lesson. You must name this function
>   biggest.

The code below is a solution to the exercise from the course.

> To complete this exercise, you should modify the code in the window
>   below. Make the following changes:
>
> - Define area(rect) to compute and return the area of a rectangle object.
> - Define biggest to be the third parameter to reduce (already defined).
> - Finish the definition of compute using a call to reduce.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Using Reduce</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/exercise.css"></link>
        <script>
    function reduce(a, base, f) {
        var result = base;
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            result = f(result, a[i]);
        return result;
    }

    // these are the rectangles to consider
    r1  = {width:  9, height: 34};    // area is 306
    r2  = {width: 10, height: 31};    // area is 310
    r3  = {width: 11, height: 28};    // area is 308
    r4  = {width: 12, height: 25};    // area is 300
    r5  = {width: 13, height: 24};    // area is 312
    r6  = {width: 14, height: 22};    // area is 308
    r7  = {width: 15, height: 20};    // 300
    r8  = {width: 16, height: 19};    // 304
    r9  = {width: 17, height: 18};    // 306
    r10 = {width: 18, height: 17};    // 306
    r11 = {width: 19, height: 16};    // 304
    r12 = {width: 20, height: 15};    // 300
    r13 = {width: 22, height: 14};    // 308
    r14 = {width: 24, height: 12};    // 288
    r15 = {width: 28, height: 11};    // 308

    // form an array of all the rectangles
    rectangles = [r1, r2,  r3,  r4,  r5,  r6,  r7, r8,
                  r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15];

    // define the function named area here:
    function area(r){

    return r.width * r.height;

    }

    // define the function named biggest here:
    function biggest(biggestYet, newRect){
    biggestYet = Math.max (biggestYet, newRect)
     return biggestYet;

    }

    // complete the definition using a call to reduce:
    function compute() {
      //  return -23; // replace with code to return the area of
                      //  the largest rectangle in rectangles
       var biggestYet = 0;

     for (x = 0 ; x < rectangles.length ; x++)
     {
       var rArea = area ( rectangles[x]);
       console.log ( "area "+ x+ "," + rArea );

       biggestYet = biggest (biggestYet, rArea);
       console.log ( "biggest "+ x +","+ biggestYet); 

     }
      return biggestYet;


    }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- the output is displayed using HTML -->
        <p>The area of the largest rectangle is:
           <!-- the ? will be replaced with the answer -->
           <div id = "answer">?</div></p>
        <br>
        <!-- a button runs compute and puts the answer into the HTML -->
        <button id = "computeButton"
            onclick = "x = compute();
                <!-- find the document element named 'answer' -->
                where = document.getElementById('answer');
                <!-- insert result x as text into the HTML -->
                where.innerHTML = x.toString();">Run compute()
                        to compute the largest rectangle.</button>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Can someone help check my codes where i went wrong because i tried many times but could not get the biggest function test to work?

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean? for the area of rectangle I understand that that the function part is correct. Probably can you assist me to understand how to compute the biggest function test using the reduce in the compute function? Thanks so much.

Comment: `rectangles.map(area).reduce(biggest, -1);`

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use the method called reduce. The issue that you are getting is because of the onclick handler. You need to look into that again.
Here is a possible solution for this:

```js
function reduce(a, base, f) {
    var result = base;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        result = f(result, a[i]);
    return result;
};

function area(rectangle) {
    return rectangle.width * rectangle.height;
};

function biggest(result, rectangle) {
    return Math.max(result, area(rectangle));
};

function compute(rectangles) {
    var x = reduce(rectangles, 0, biggest);
    var where = document.getElementById('answer');
        where.innerHTML = x.toString();
};

var r1  = {width:  9, height: 34};    // area is 306
var r2  = {width: 10, height: 31};    // area is 310
var r3  = {width: 11, height: 28};    // area is 308
var r4  = {width: 12, height: 25};    // area is 300
var r5  = {width: 13, height: 24};    // area is 312
var r6  = {width: 14, height: 22};    // area is 308
var r7  = {width: 15, height: 20};    // 300
var r8  = {width: 16, height: 19};    // 304
var r9  = {width: 17, height: 18};    // 306
var r10 = {width: 18, height: 17};    // 306
var r11 = {width: 19, height: 16};    // 304
var r12 = {width: 20, height: 15};    // 300
var r13 = {width: 22, height: 14};    // 308
var r14 = {width: 24, height: 12};    // 288
var r15 = {width: 28, height: 11};    // 308

// form an array of all the rectangles
var rectangles = [r1, r2,  r3,  r4,  r5,  r6,  r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15];

document.getElementById('computeButton').onclick = function() {
    compute(rectangles);
};
```

```html
        <!-- the output is displayed using HTML -->
        <p>The area of the largest rectangle is:
           <!-- the ? will be replaced with the answer -->
           <div id = "answer">?</div></p>
        <br>
        <!-- a button runs compute and puts the answer into the HTML -->
        <button id = "computeButton">Run compute()
                        to compute the largest rectangle.</button>
```

Or the whole program as oneliner:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, rectangles.map(area));
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian :) Noted on the onclick handler part.

Answer (score 0):

The reduce function needs you to pass in an array, a base value, and a function:

The array of rectangles is provided.

The `base` predefined as 0.

The biggest function is called with 2 arguments, `"biggestYet"` and `"newRect"`. `biggestYet` is int value of the biggest area seen yet. The newRect is a rectangle object. To compare the `biggestYet` to the `newRect` we need to call the `area` function on the `newRect`.

```
function biggest(biggestYet, newRect) {
  return Math.max(biggestYet, area(newRect)); 
}
```

Putting all of this together:

```
function compute() {
  return reduce(rectangles, 0, biggest);
}
```

---

```js
function reduce(a, base, f) {
  var result = base;
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    result = f(result, a[i]);
  return result;
}

function area(r) {
  return r.width * r.height;
}

function biggest(biggestYet, newRect) {
  return Math.max(biggestYet, area(newRect)); 
}

function compute() {
  return reduce(rectangles, 0, biggest);
}

var r1  = {width:  9, height: 34};
var r2  = {width: 10, height: 31};
var r3  = {width: 11, height: 28};
var r4  = {width: 12, height: 25};
var r5  = {width: 13, height: 24};
var r6  = {width: 14, height: 22};
var r7  = {width: 15, height: 20};
var r8  = {width: 16, height: 19};
var r9  = {width: 17, height: 18};
var r10 = {width: 18, height: 17};
var r11 = {width: 19, height: 16};
var r12 = {width: 20, height: 15};
var r13 = {width: 22, height: 14};
var r14 = {width: 24, height: 12};
var r15 = {width: 28, height: 11};
var rectangles = [r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15];
```

```html
<div>
  The area of the largest rectangle is:
  <div id="answer">?</div>
</div>
<button id = "computeButton"
onclick = "x = compute();
    <!-- find the document element named 'answer' -->
    where = document.getElementById('answer');
    <!-- insert result x as text into the HTML -->
    where.innerHTML = x.toString();">Run compute()
            to compute the largest rectangle.</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much DTing for the help. :) It makes me understand the logic behind it.